# Good RSS Feed Parser to use on php file?

Tags: php, rss

Was trying to use EmbedRSS Plugin but the php code that I used to put it into my index.php file doesn't work.

```
 [cetsEmbedRSS id='http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com' itemcount='2' itemauthor='1' itemdate='1' itemcontent='1']
```

convert into php:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode ('[cetsEmbedRSS id='http://deannaschneider.wordpress.com' itemcount='2' itemauthor='1' itemdate='1' itemcontent='1']'); ?>
```

I switched to Wordpress's built in rss and used the following code:

```
 <?php include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/rss.php');
 wp_rss('http://www.ssupremacy.com/bbs/rss.php?fid=3', 10); ?>
```

When I replace "3" with "4", the feed shows but it doesn't show in fid=3.  And I want more to show then just a list of links.  I want an excerpt of the forum post, date, author, etc.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`wp_rss` is deprecated and you should use  `fetch_feed` instead which gives you much more control and options over the RSS and what is fetched ex:

```
<?php 
// Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');

// Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
$rss = fetch_feed('http://example.com/rss/feed/goes/here');
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : // Checks that the object is created correctly 
        // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5. 
        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5); 

        // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    else
    // Loop through each feed item and display each item as a hyperlink.
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) { ?>
    <li>
        <a href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>'
        title='<?php echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>'>
        <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></a> <small>By: </small>
        <?php echo esc_html($item->get_author()) ; ?> <br />
        <?php echo esc_html($item->get_description()) ; ?>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

you can read more at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed

Comment: Had to remove the <small>By: </small> code because I didn't get any author names....what showed up was random characters.  Also, in each feed item, whenever there is a break in the item, the html code <br /> appears.  How do I make it so that the code doesn't appear in the feed?  It's as if the source code within parsed feed is not rendering.

Comment: The code i posted is an example and not a copy paste solution.

Comment: Yea, I know...I've started tweaking the code so it looks good on my site but the breaks in the feed items still show up as <br />.  The feed parser doesn't render the html.

Comment: remove `esc_html` from the item description